Flutter firebase cloud function init error
I'm trying to initialize cloud functions in my Flutter project and I'm getting this
? Would you like to initialize a new codebase, or overwrite an existing one? Overwrite

Overwriting codebase default...

? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript
? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? No
✔  Wrote functions/package.json
✔  Wrote functions/index.js
✔  Wrote functions/.gitignore
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /Users/ebenoasis/Desktop/hitchride_new/functions/node_modules/protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command /Users/ebenoasis/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! /bin/sh: --: invalid option
npm ERR! Usage: /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
npm ERR!        /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
npm ERR! GNU long options:
npm ERR!        --debug
npm ERR!        --debugger
npm ERR!        --dump-po-strings
npm ERR!        --dump-strings
npm ERR!        --help
npm ERR!        --init-file
npm ERR!        --login
npm ERR!        --noediting
npm ERR!        --noprofile
npm ERR!        --norc
npm ERR!        --posix
npm ERR!        --protected
npm ERR!        --rcfile
npm ERR!        --restricted
npm ERR!        --verbose
npm ERR!        --version
npm ERR!        --wordexp
npm ERR! Shell options:
npm ERR!        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
npm ERR!        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ebenoasis/.npm/_logs/2024-04-18T19_26_02_635Z-debug-0.log

NPM install failed, continuing with Firebase initialization...

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!

And when I try to deploy it with firebase deploy I get this erro. Can anyone help me solve this issue?
=== Deploying to 'hitchride-d39b5'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! Missing script: "lint"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     npm link # Symlink a package folder
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ebenoasis/.npm/_logs/2024-04-18T19_31_39_663Z-debug-0.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

I don't know how to solve this. I would be grateful if someone helped fix the errors.
I don't know why I'm getting npm ERR!.

In your package.json, change your lint to: "lint": "eslint" or if you're not using lint then just leave it blank: "lint": "". Check out these links: link1, link2

Thank you. My lint is already "lint": "eslint .". So what do I do with the index.js in order not to use the schedule time?
